# propTypes in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

```
x.propTypes = {
type: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

I get the following error when using `isRequired` for `PropTypes`.

TypeError: prop_type__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.string is undefined

Comment: How are you importing `PropTypes`?

Comment: import PropTypes from 'prop-type'

Comment: do you mean `prop-types`? Is that a typo? If not then that's the issue.

Comment: Yes. I realized. I had imported it by mistake

Comment: did you try with  
```x.propTypes = {
   type: PropTypes.string
}
```